# Powerpoint : What is the event fired after transitioned to the next slide?

Tags: vba, events, powerpoint

Powerpoint has an event [`SlideShowNextSlide`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/application-slideshowonnext-event-powerpoint?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which is triggered just before the slide show transitioned to the next slide.

What is the event that is triggered **after** the slide show has transitioned to the next slide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to bookmark this page from Chirag Dalal:

http://www.officeoneonline.com/vba/events_version.html

I'm not sure that the specific event you're looking for exists.

But something like this might do the job:

```
Sub OnSlideShowPageChange(ByVal Wn As SlideShowWindow)
    MsgBox Wn.View.Slide.SlideIndex
End Sub
```

This event fires during a slide show when the slide changes to either next slide or previous slide.

Comment: +1 for the helpful link. I want to run a piece of code every time the user has transitioned to any slide. For example, after user has transitioned into slide 2 from slide 1, this piece of code would trigger a timer in slide 2.

Comment: Have a look at the edited version of my answer, then, @Mark